# Magento 2 - Get currency of an order item

Tags: magento2, orders, currency

I get the order items from order using:

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
```

How can I get the currency of an order item? We have products that sell in different store using different currency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```
$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
$order->getOrderCurrencyCode();
//$order->getBaseCurrencyCode();
//$order->getGlobalCurrencyCode();
```

Look at `sales_order` table to see some currency types.

Comment: Is possible do it with a quote?